# Does it make sense to whiten the data in order to apply a matched filtering algorithm if my dataset consist of a sinusoid + random Gaussian noise?

Tags: data-analysis, signal-processing, noise

With a Python program I generated a sinusoid signal and I added to it Gaussian noise.
Now I want to compute the optimal SNR by applying a matched filtering algorithm.
Since the noise is white (at least I think it is, I did not make any assumption on its distribution in frequency), does it make sense to whiten the data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have analytical equations for the signal $S$ and for the noise $N$. The $S/N$ ratio has an analytical expression as well. What are you therefore expecting to vary to search for an "optimal" $S/N$?

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer Isn't in this way matched filtering work?
I mean, the idea behind the algorithm is trying to maximize the SNR, at least this is what I understood

Comment: @Community 
I have done a program that generates a time series which is a sine, then I added a random Gaussian noise to it:
When the noise is not white, in order to apply the matched filtering algorithm one has "whiten" the data.
In this case noise is already white, so, does it make any senso to whiten the data?

Comment: Please add your explanations to the question rather than adding them to the comments. Also, it seems that you are using a defined processing method, and you are questioning why the method requires you to do something. Please reference the method with more details.

Comment: Are you sure this is physics-related question? I would ask that one on CrossValidated or Data Science Stack Exchange.